# Uncaught TypeError: not a function -JavaScript Cloud Computing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

I am writing a web app to store appointments for a user, so far only an "add appointment" feature has been implemented. The error i am getting is after i load a list of all of the appointments and then use a click function on one of the list items, the Chrome console gives me this error... 
"Uncaught TypeError: this.appointmentClicked is not a function"

code in question....

```
$("#appointments li").click(function() {
                    // Call the appointmentClicked(...) function.
                    // The parameter is the ID of the appointment clicked.
                    // See how we get the ID from the located li element/tag.

                appointmentClicked($(this).attr("id"));
```

this is the function that IS defined.... in the same file...

```
function appointmentClicked(id) {
      $("#appointments li").removeClass("selected"); //remove all list items from the class "selected, thus clearing previous selection

      // Find the selected appointment (i.e. list item) and add the class "selected" to it.
      // This will highlight it according to the "selected" class.
      $("#" + id).addClass("selected");

      //retrieve appointment coordinates from appointment service
      var url = baseURL + "/appointment/" + id; //URL of service, notice that ID is part of URL path

      //use jQuery shorthand Ajax function to get JSON data
      $.getJSON(url, //URL of service
        function(jsonData) //successful callback function
        {
          duration = jsonData["duration"]; //get duration from JSON data
          owner = jsonData["owner"]; //get owner from JSON data
          showappointment(duration, owner);
        }
      );
} //end function
```

All help is appreciated :)

Jay

Comment: Apparently the "lost" function is out of the scope of the caller.

Comment: You open/close functions properly? They are in a same scope?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function appointmentClicked(id) {
      $("#appointments li").removeClass("selected"); //remove all list items from the class "selected, thus clearing previous selection

      // Find the selected appointment (i.e. list item) and add the class "selected" to it.
      // This will highlight it according to the "selected" class.
      $("#" + id).addClass("selected");

      //retrieve appointment coordinates from appointment service
      var url = baseURL + "/appointment/" + id; //URL of service, notice that ID is part of URL path

      //use jQuery shorthand Ajax function to get JSON data
      $.getJSON(url, //URL of service
        function(jsonData) //successful callback function
        {
          duration = jsonData["duration"]; //get duration from JSON data
          owner = jsonData["owner"]; //get owner from JSON data
          showappointment(duration, owner);
        }
      );
}
$(function(){
$("#appointments li").click(function() {
                    // Call the appointmentClicked(...) function.
                    // The parameter is the ID of the appointment clicked.
                    // See how we get the ID from the located li element/tag.

                appointmentClicked($(this).attr("id"));
}           
}
```

Comment: $(function(){
what is the purpose of this extra line?